# Best split for inheritance

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I asked this in mathoverflow, perhaps here someone can help.
I am trying to figure out algorithms for solving the following problem:
I have a set of assets $A = \{ a_i : i = 1\ldots n \}$ which I want to split between two agents $v$ and $w$, the value of each asset for each agent is $v_i = v(a_i)$ and $w_i = w(a_i)$. So I am looking for two disjoint, complementary sets $A^v$ and $A^w$, $A^v \cup A^w = A$, of given cardinality ($n$ and $n-k$ say) such that $$\sum_{a \in A^v} v(a) + \sum_{a\in A^w}w(a)$$ Be a maximum.
Otherwise say I want to split my inheritage in a way that the happiness of my two kids will be maximum. Any pointer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add and subtract $\sum_{a\in A^w} v(a)$ you find that your function depends only on the value of $\sum_{a\in A^w} w(a)-v(a)$. Now you have only a function $f(a)=w(a)-v(a)$ and you need to find the maximum sum of $k$ or $n-k$ elements which is done simply by adding them from the highest to the lowest.

Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Hey karmalu indeed nicely solved, what about several agents?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can use the same method inductively